# Intune Graph API Errors

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, intune

I'm trying to download/upload the MSI of an Intune mobile app.

I can get the app list using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps
```

I can also get the details of a single mobile app using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/
```

But getting the content versions of the mobile app using the following calls fails:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/contentVersions
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/microsoft.graph.managedMobileLobApp/contentVersions
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/microsoft.graph.mobileLobApp/contentVersions
```

The documentation says that all three versions should work: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_apps_managedmobilelobapp_list_mobileappcontent

But I always get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'contentVersions'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "94029de8-0bd4-4726-9138-d3c785e91be3",
            "date": "2017-08-18T20:58:50"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "No method match route template",
        "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/singleton/navigation/key/cast/navigation with http verb GET for request /StatelessAppMetadataFEService/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps('42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799')/$/microsoft.management.services.api.managedMobileLobApp/contentVersions.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b1167613-6f5e-409d-835d-e2774d58e14a",
            "date": "2017-08-18T20:59:14"
        }
    }
}
```

Do i not understand the documentation correctly or is there anything else I'm doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

@Tobi 
 To quickly see the answer skip until you see ***ANSWER***

---

As you have correctly stated, the full app list along with their metadata can be obtain via:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps
```

In that you will get a list of mobileLobApps and managedMobileLobApps. 
For example:

- A mobileLobApp metadata

  ```
      {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidLobApp",
      "id": "<the GUID for mobileLobApp>",
      "displayName": "TestApp.apk",
      "description": "TestApp.apk",
      "publisher": "testPublisher",
      "largeIcon": null,
      "createdDateTime": "<some date>",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "<some date>",
      "isFeatured": false,
      "privacyInformationUrl": null,
      "informationUrl": null,
      "owner": null,
      "developer": null,
      "notes": null,
      "uploadState": 1,
      "committedContentVersion": "2",
      "fileName": "TestApp.apk",
      "size": 1262448,
      "identityVersion": "110",
      "identityName": "<some test app info>",
      "minimumSupportedOperatingSystem": {
          "v4_0": true,
          "v4_0_3": false,
          "v4_1": false,
          "v4_2": false,
          "v4_3": false,
          "v4_4": false,
          "v5_0": false,
          "v5_1": false
      },
      "versionName": null,
      "versionCode": "<version info here>"
  },
  ```

  - A managedMobileLobApp metadata

    ```
     {
     "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.managedIOSLobApp",
    "id": "<the GUID for managedMobileLobApp>",
    "displayName": "<Display name of the managed App>",
    "description": "<desc>",
    "publisher": "<publisher>",
    "largeIcon": null,
    "createdDateTime": "<date time info>",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "<date/time info>",
    "isFeatured": false,
    "privacyInformationUrl": "",
    "informationUrl": null,
    "owner": "",
    "developer": "",
    "notes": "",
    "uploadState": 1,
    "appAvailability": "lineOfBusiness",
    "version": "\"398c8e35-60db-4f07-a424-e17484a48f30\"",
    "committedContentVersion": "1",
    "fileName": "Excel_DF_2_4_17070200.ipa",
    "size": 138493616,
    "identityVersion": "2.4.17070200",
    "bundleId": "com.microsoft.Office.Excel-dogfood",
    "applicableDeviceType": {
        "iPad": true,
        "iPhoneAndIPod": true
    },
    "minimumSupportedOperatingSystem": {
        "v8_0": false,
        "v9_0": true,
        "v10_0": false,
        "v11_0": false
    },
    "expirationDateTime": "2017-12-05T23:55:42Z",
    "versionNumber": null,
    "buildNumber": "2.4.17070200"
    ```

    },

In your case you can simply get the app metadata for your particular app via:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799
```

From the response of the above GET call you can figure out whether the app is managed (managedMobileLobApp) or not(mobileLobApp), by looking at the @odata.type.

***ANSWER***:
If the app is non-managed, th the following call should give you the contentVersions

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799
```

/microsoft.graph.mobileLobApp/contentVersions

Else, if the app is managed then:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799
```

/microsoft.graph.managedMobileLobApp/contentVersions

Reason: the call should work with base (mobileLobApp or managedMobileLobApp) as well as the derived type of the app:

- androidLobApp (base mobileLobApp)
- iosStoreApp (base mobileLobApp)
- windowsMobileMSI (base mobileLobApp)
- managedAndroidStoreApp (base managedMobileLobApp)
  etc...

(In case you need to know the graph schema for all the supported app types go here [enter link description here](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata))

On a side note: By the time you submitted the question the above call was broken. However, the solution given by @Andrei Fedorov has been working all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/microsoft.graph.windowsMobileMSI/contentVersions
```

For example you can get the first file content

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/42454cd8-cba9-4946-bae2-b66e7ca54799/microsoft.graph.windowsMobileMSI/contentVersions/1/files
```

I managed to get the list of content files, However I failed short to upload my MSI file or update existing file content.

Answer (score -1):

this is valid bug. we are working on to support that. looks we missed adding routing rules to support it on some of base types of mobile apps. thanks for the reports. we will fix it in next couple of weeks.